# Windows file: using both ReadFile and mapping

Tags: c++, windows, file, memory

Suppose I have a file on disk and then create its handle using `CreateFile`, its mapping object using `CreateFileMapping`, its mapping view using `MapViewOfFile`. The start of the file address in virtual memory is held in pointer `StartPtr` which was returned by `MapViewOfFile` function. If, before calling `CreateFileMapping` function, I use `ReadFile` to read some bytes `N`, would be the pointer returned by `MapViewOfFile` point to (`StartPtr` + `N`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  MapViewOfFile() requires you telling it where the view is mapped relative from the start of the file.  Specified in the dwFileOffset arguments.  If you *need* it to work this way then simply use SetFilePointerEx() with a zero move to obtain the current position.

Answer (score 2):

No. **ReadFile** only move on-disk file pointer.